# I have this error CS1001 (C#) and CS1026 ..But do not know how tosolve it

Tags: c#, razor, webmatrix

i got this error:

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1001: Identifier expected
```

from this set of code:

```
var reqcategory=""; 
        foreach(Request["category"] as reqcategory)
        {
        var sql5 = "SELECT Type.PreReq1, Type.PreReq2, (CASE WHEN (Type.PreReq1 IS NOT NULL) AND (PermitApp1.RPClass IS NULL) AND (PermitApp1.RPCategory IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing1, (CASE WHEN (Type.PreReq2 IS NOT NULL) AND (PermitApp2.RPClass IS NULL) AND (PermitApp2.RPCategory IS NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS missing2 FROM Type LEFT JOIN PermitApp AS PermitApp1 ON (Type.PreReq1=PermitApp1.RPClass) OR (Type.PreReq1=PermitApp1.RPCategory) AND ( PermitApp1.CDSID = @0 ) AND (PermitApp1.MDecision='1') LEFT JOIN PermitApp AS PermitApp2 ON (Type.PreReq2=PermitApp2.RPClass) OR (Type.PreReq2=PermitApp2.RPCategory) AND ( PermitApp2.CDSID = @1 ) AND (PermitApp2.MDecision='1') WHERE Type.PType = @2";
        var result = db.QuerySingle(sql5, myCDSID, myCDSID, reqcategory);
        var miss1 = result.missing1;
        var miss2 = result.missing2;
        }
```

The error happens to fall on this line:

```
foreach(Request["category"] as reqcategory)
```

as highlighted by the compiler.

Can anyone tell me what is my mistake?? And How should i declare a identifier??

Anyway what is an identifier? I cant seem to undertstand the explaination in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b839hwk4(VS.80).aspx

If its int i will use `int.parse` right but if it is string...how can i do so?

Thanks Thanks

BTW I am using webmatrix...

After i used JaredPar's solution...the next error came...

```
CS1026: ) expected
```

in this part:

```
if (miss1 == '1' or miss2 == '1'){
            ModelState.AddError("missing", "You have not met the Pre-Requisites for "+ cat +" yet.")
            } else if (miss1 == '0' and miss2 == '0'){

        Session["license"] = Request["licence"];
        Session["from"] = Request["from"];
        Session["to"] = Request["to"];
        Session["group"] = Request["group"];
        Session["class1"] = Request["class1"];
        Session["category1"] = Request["category1"];
        Session["class"] = Request["class"];
        Session["category"] = Request["category"];
        Response.Redirect("~/Questionnaire");
        }
```

on this line:

```
if (miss1 == '1' or miss2 == '1'){
```

Thanks...I don't see why i need a '(' there...as i have closed all of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you have the structure of the `foreach` loop backwards.  In C# it's `identifire in collection`.

```
foreach(var reqcategory in Request["category"]) { 
  ...
}
```

Note that even this won't be enough though as `Request[...]` returns `object` which isn't a valid collection type in C#.  You'll need to specify the type of the underlying collection or use `dynamic`.  The safest choice is a cast to `IEnumerable`

```
foreach(object reqcategory in (IEnumerable)Request["category"]) { 
  ...
}
```

Comment: hi...Thanks...do you mind to help me in one more problem?? its related as it is right below the  set of code i put...I edited my question. Thanks

Comment: or should i open another qns?

Comment: Or sorry i found the reason...thanks Or is not valid in C#...have to use ||